# how to hook up a UIBarButtonItem to play a audiofile programmatically without using IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, action, uibarbuttonitem

Can we use the *addTarget* **function** to hook into the *UIControlEventTouchUpInside* **event** with the *UIBarButtonItem*.

Basically i am trying to hook UIBarButtonItem Play into the UIControlEventTouchUpInside programmticaly without using IB to play the audio file when pressed by using addTarget function.

I m getting error that UIBarButtonItem may not respond to 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents:'

```
UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(play:)];
systemItem1.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

[systemItem1 addTarget:self action:@selector(playaudio) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your init call, you're already setting a target and an action.  That's all you need to do.

So take out the `addTarget` line as you're already doing the right thing in the init call.

If you want to do ***both*** the play and playaudio methods... create one method that calls both and set that as the item's action.

`addTarget` exists for UIControl, which a [`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is not descended from.

Comment: So then how i will link my audio file with this UIBarButtonItem. So that whenever this buttonitem is pressed it plays audiofile.

Comment: Send `-playaudio` to `self` in the `-play:` method.